# matlab problems calculating with image

Tags: matlab

I'm using the follwing code in matlab to calculate with an image:

```
Image = imread('whatever.tif'); % 16 Bit tiff 
Image = -0.92091+5.18112E-5*Image ; % I want to change the pixel values
```

It seems that matlab does not calculate values below 1 or above 65535 (16 Bit). The values I expect are between 0 and 1.

What can I do to get the correct values? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should first convert type of your data. `Image = -0.92091+5.18112E-5*double(Image);`

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thanks!